# While loop in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

How do I create a similar loop in Freemarker(FTL)
In freemarker I have this statement:

```
<#if myVariable?? >
  // do stuff
</#if>
```

and I want to convert it to a while loop is it possible?

Javascript-code I want to replicate

```
while (myVariable != null) {
  // do stuff
}
```

If not possible how is the recursive approach in Freemarker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template language only supports looping via `#list`. So if you need to do that kind of loop, the a workaround is this:

```
<#list 0..1000000000 as _>
  <#if exitCondition><#break></#if>
  ...
</#list>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `macro` with  recursion:

```
<#macro doStuff>
  <#if myVariable?? >
    // do stuff
    <@doStuff/>
  </#if>
</#macro>

<@doStuff/>
```

Answer (score 0):

And to complete the picture, an implementation in function form that uses other functions as input to do processing and evaluate the condition to continue or not:

```html
<#function while(input, fn, condition, args = [])>
    <#if !fn?is_directive || !condition?is_directive>
            <#return 'No processing or condition function provided!' />
    </#if>
 
    <#local result = fn(input, args) />

    <#return condition(result)?then(result, while(result, fn, condition, args)) />
</#function>


<#-- Helper functions that would do the processing and provide the condition -->
<#function $length(input = '', max = 6)>
    <#return (input?length >= max) />
</#function>

<#function $add(input = '', args = [])>
    <#return input?right_pad(input?length+1, 'x') />
</#function>


${while('ab', $add, $length)} => 'abxxxx'
```

Just be aware, that with any of those approaches you could bring down your server if your exit condition is faulty and leads to an infinite loop, like in every other language as well ;)